# Scrolling in the tags view is very choppy

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Scrolling in the Tags view/tab is acceptable while dragging but quite laggy when you let go. Everywhere else (that I've) found is much better.

I'm using an iPhone 5 running iOS 7.1

Comment: Yeah, something weird is happening there.  It's a bit gittery and it's profiling at 40fps when everyone else does 60.  Looking at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in the next build.

I'm not sure why (likely something internal) but setting the corner radius on the label itself was messing with the rendering performance.  There were no red flags when I inspected it other than the FPS drop that went away when I disabled it.  I've moved the tag bubble to be a separate layer and things are fast again.  The dangers of making changes to layers you don't own I guess.